# UNIX to datatime conversion

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert the data type of a date/time column from `int64` to datetime but it's in UNIX so by default the date is set to 1970.

I've tried changing the unit to seconds, milliseconds, nanoseconds, microseconds, and days but the result is still set on 1970.

```
# Convert the timestamp column to datetime
weather['time_stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(weather['time_stamp'],origin='unix', unit='ms')

# After converting the timestamp column to datetime datatype.
# Create a datetime object from the year, month and day column as well as 
# the hour and minute column.

weather['year'] = weather['time_stamp'].map(lambda x : x.year)
weather['month'] = weather['time_stamp'].map(lambda x : x.month)
weather['day'] = weather['time_stamp'].map(lambda x : x.day)
weather['hour'] = weather['time_stamp'].map(lambda x : x.hour)
weather['minute'] = weather['time_stamp'].map(lambda x : x.minute)
weather.take(np.random.permutation(len(weather))[:15]
```

What am I doing wrong? I've used this method before and it worked well.
I even added
`format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'` to the syntax but still no change.

This is the input:

```
time_stamp
1545003901
```

This is the output:

```
time_stamp                  year  month  day  hour minute
1970-01-18 20:42:22.520     1970  1      18   20   42
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: "so by default the date is set to 1970." that's not how a unix timestamp works.

Comment: The date is still set to 1st January 1970, when it should be 2018, I don't understand why

Comment: Please give some example input data and output from your attempt.

Comment: oh my bad, that's how I understood when I read the statement  "For Unix, the epoch is January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 " off a website

Comment: I've added a single row of the output, basically the entire column displays the same date, the same hour with varying minutes

Answer (score 1):

Your input has ten digits, so this perhaps is the unix time in seconds (seconds since 1970/1/1). If so, you need to set `unit="s"`.

```py
pd.to_datetime(1545003901, unit="s")
#Timestamp('2018-12-16 23:45:01')
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, let me try that out again